# How to insert detail band between the existing bands in iReport?

Tags: java, ireport

Simple question. How to insert detail band between the existing bands in iReport?
For example, I have current situation:

---

Detail 1

---

Detail 2

---

Detail 3

---

... and I want to add another detail band between Detail 2 and Detail 3. Is there any simple way?

Many thanks.

EDIT: I meant on designer / XML view.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution. I switched into XML view and copied everything between `<band>` and `</band>` tags and put into desired position. Sorry for bothering.

Comment: Google took me here when looking for this same issue, but I thought that "without having to do manually copy&paste in the XML view" was implicit in the question, as that option was straightforward to me. I want to explicitly avoid messing directly with XML because it's easy to get the wrong bands.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple details band are available probably since version  3.5.0 of JasperReport.

```
JasperDesignFactory designFactory = new JasperDesignFactory();
JRBandFactory bandFactory = new JRBandFactory();

JasperDesign design = (JasperDesign)  designFactory.createObject(designAttributes);
JRDesignSection designSection = (JRDesignSection) design.getDetailSection();

JRDesignBand band1 = (JRDesignBand) bandFactory.createObject(bandAttributes);
JRDesignBand band2 = (JRDesignBand) bandFactory.createObject(bandAttributes);
JRDesignBand band3 = (JRDesignBand) bandFactory.createObject(bandAttributes);

designSection.addBand(band1);
designSection.addBand(band2);
designSection.addBand(band3);
```

More or less that how it goes.

In XML, you just create another band like default one

In Designer that depend of the designer. For example in iReport (3.7.1):

Go to "Report Inspector View", right click on default detail band and from context menu you pick "Add Another Detail Band".

Comment: If you pick "Add Another Detail Band" in iReport 4.0, you get detail band **at the bottom** of all other detail bands. My question is rather pointed on situation where you have existing detail bands and you want to insert another one **between** the existing bands. Anyway, many thanks.

Comment: In iReport 3.7.1 works as should or as you expected. Probably that is a bug or something else you have did the current stable is 4.0.1 work also as should.

Comment: I doubt it, @DamianLeszczyński-Vash. In iReport 4.5.1 every new band gets added after the previous ones, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop bands in OUTLINE window. 
So solution in "Design View" will be add new Band and Drag it where you want in OUTLINE window.

i am about JasperStudio, may be it was not possible for IReport

Comment: Not possible in iReport, at least not dragging the bands to the desired position in the Report Inspector window.